# Can I find out the length of an array without using .length in Java

Tags: java

I have the following:

```
int count = args.length;
```

Strange as it might seem I want to find out the array length without using the length field. Is there any other way?

Here's what I already (without success) tried:

```
int count=0; while (args [count] !=null) count ++;
int count=0; while (!(args[count].equals(""))) count ++;}
```

Comment: You could try accessing successive character positions until you get an out of bounds exception.  Not that I would recommend doing that...

Comment: Well, you get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if you access an element beyond the end of the array, so you could always iterate inside a `try/catch` block, and note the index that first threw the exception.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

How about `Arrays.asList(yourArray).size();`?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that there is any need to do this. However, the easiest way to do this ,is to use the `enhanced for loop`

```
 int count=0;
 for(int i:array)
 {
   count++;
 }

 System.out.println(count);
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you would want to do anything else, but this is just something I came up with to see what would work. This works for me:

```
    int count = 0;
    int[] someArray = new int[5];  
    int temp;
    try
    {
        while(true)
        {
            temp = someArray[count];
            count++;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
           System.out.println(count); 
    }
```

Comment: We do try not to promote worst practices (such as using exceptions for control flow, particularly in lieu of better alternatives), because the strange thing is people tend to find *and use* them.

Comment: Ah ok, yeah I wouldn't recommend anyone actually using this approach. The best way would always be to use .length, to the best of my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use [] to access an array if the index is out of bound.

You can use for-each loop

```
for (String s: args){
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ArrayLength {
    static int number[] = { 1, 5, 8, 5, 6, 2, 4, 5, 1, 8, 9, 6, 4, 7, 4, 7, 5, 1, 3, 55, 74, 47, 98, 282, 584, 258, 548,
            56 };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        calculatingLength();
    System.out.println(number.length);
    }

    public static void calculatingLength() {
        int i = 0;
        for (int num : number) {

            i++;

        }
        System.out.println("Total Size Of Array :" + i);

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int[] intArray = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 7, 5, 3 };
    int count = 0;
    // System.out.println("No of Elements in an Array using Length:
    // "+intArray.length);

    System.out.println("Elements in an Array: ");
    for (int i : intArray) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
        count++;
    }

    System.out.println("\nCount: " + count);
```